# Javascript-OpenERP: Modify/replace POS template view

Tags: javascript, odoo

So basically, I'm trying to introduce modifications in OpenERP's POS inteface from version 6.1. I see that the layout of this view can be found at /static/src/xml/pos.xml. What I want is to modify this view from my own addon (thus, not altering the original pos addon) and as far as I know, there is no way of inheriting this view to add changes (or is there?). So after studying the module, I'm trying to override its js function to slip in my own pos.xml with all my modifications (a copy of the original pos.xml, but with name 'PointOfSale_Mine' and other modifications). So far, I have added my own .js as follows:

```
openerp.my_pos = function(db) {


db.point_of_sale.PointOfSale = db.point_of_sale.PointOfSale.extend({

    render: function() {
        this._super.apply(this,arguments);
        return qweb_template("PointOfSale_Mine")();

        //return this._super.qweb_template("PointOfSale_Mine")();
        //return db.point_of_sale.qweb_template("PointOfSale_Mine")();
        }
    })

};
```

And of course, I'm getting the error "qweb_template is not defined" as my JS skills and my knowledge regarding OpenERP6.1's new web framework is quite limited. I would really like to know how can I call the same method that the original 'render' function calls (You can see my useless attempts commented in the code above). Or is my whole approach wrong and there is a better way of introducing my changes to the template?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After some trial and errors I came up with this code to do the trick:

```
openerp.my_pos = function(db) {


db.point_of_sale.PointOfSale = db.point_of_sale.PointOfSale.extend({

    render: function() {
        var rend = this._super();

        var jdoc = $(rend);
        jdoc.find('.pos-payment-container').prepend('<input type="text" value=""/>')

        return jdoc[0].outerHTML;
        }
    })

};
```

It does not replace the entire pos.xml template as I was initially attempting, but it is probably better as you inherit the current template and introduce your modifications only (even if you have to *.prepend()* a big chunk of html code)